# Symfony2 HTTPS requirement behind EC2 load balancer

Tags: symfony, amazon-ec2

What is a clean, Symfony way of ensuring HTTPS is being used in Symfony2 when behind an EC2 load balancer that is handling the SSL connection and sending it to you as HTTP.

If you do something like requires_channel you get a redirect loop after the initial change to HTTPS because on the webserver itself you are still doing HTTP. The url does show HTTPS though, and Amazon provide a X-FORWARDED-PROTO header to use as well.

Is there a clean way of having symfony2 handle this kind of situation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should check if [this method](https://github.com/symfony/HttpFoundation/blob/master/Request.php#L447) is suitable for you.

In your `app.php` before the `$kernel->handle(...);` you should set:

```
Request::trustProxyData();
```

**UPDATE:**

You can also configure your application in `config.yml` (see [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#trust-proxy-headers)):

```
framework:
    ...
    trust-proxy-headers: true
```

Comment: Thank you - that's exactly it!

Comment: In regards to your UPDATE this has changed as it needs to be: ```trusted_proxies:  [192.0.0.1, 10.0.0.0/8]``` - updating to use the IP CIDR range of the proxy. (see current [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-proxies))

Comment: @MattRardon Can it be related to different Symfony2 versions?

Comment: @thecatontheflat Sorry that is exactly what I meant to say. Version 2.3 now requires you to specify which proxy IP ranges to trust.

Comment: This has changed again for AWS since there's no predictable IP CIDR range for ELB.  Now we're supposed to trust all proxies and make sure the EC2 instance only accepts traffic from the load balancer.  The latest is in the Symfony docs.

Answer (score 0):

The trusted_proxies option was removed in Symfony 3.3. 
See [How to Configure Symfony to Work behind a Load Balancer or a Reverse Proxy](http://symfony.com/doc/current/request/load_balancer_reverse_proxy.html).